# How to prevent ajax form submission written anywhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing a plugin based on another pro plugins in WordPress. 
I would like to stop an ajax form submission which is written in another plugin. ***I can't change ajax code in another plugin.***

**Current Scenario**

When I submit a form, it will take me to the new page but with **that it also running an ajax request.** I want to stop that ajax request. **Simply, I just want to submit my form normally with new page.**

---

**HTML**

```
<form id="redirect_form" class="abc-form" method="post" name="New Form" action="http://example.com/form-redirect">
    <label for="form-field-field_1" class="abc-field-label">Test</label>
    <input type="text" name="form_fields[field_1]" id="form-field-field_1" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off">            
    <button type="submit" class="form_redirect_to">Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  jQuery('#redirect_form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).off("submit");
    this.submit();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you not change the ID of your form ? This way the Jquery function won't be triggered

Comment: @RomainV This form was not have any ID before so I have added ID to run our jquery before the default one.

Comment: Ok, just to make sure, the JQuery you provide is yours but there is also another Jquery function binded to this element ? If yes, how the default Jquery is bind to the form ? By the class, by the ID , or by the tag maybe ?

Comment: It's binded using class from another js

Comment: Ok, so at the moment you have '<form id="redirect_form" class="abc-form">' . Can you not modify it to '<form id="redirect_form" class="another-class">' ? This way the other Jquery events won't be triggered

Comment: ok, Let me try that

Comment: @RomainV Thanks, It is working like a charm. Hurray!
I also wanted to find the solution to prevent any kind of ajax also. Although Thank you . This is what I want. I accepted as a anwser. Can you please add your answer so that I can accept it and give upvote to you for your effort

Comment: No problem :) Thanks @Mayank

Comment: This is a totally ridiculous question and conversation. on the first comment, he said to remove selector which trigger the ajax. but you are refusing to do that and then now same thing is your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned it by comment, the default Jquery event is bind using the class of the form. 
By changing the default class, the event won't be triggered anymore in the default Jquery function.

Change:

```
<form id="redirect_form" class="abc-form">
```

By:

```
<form id="redirect_form" class="another-class">
```